# App invite dialog delegate methods result parameter contains no request id

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

In `fb-sdk 3.x`. I was able to get `request id` after user has sent requests to their friends(using`FBWebDialog`s) this way I could show in my app that user has invited friends which improved user experience because user got confirmation that invites were sent.

Now with `fb-sdk 4.0`(using `FBSDKAppInviteDialog`) I don't receive any data which would enable me to show invited friends.

Do you have any suggestions how to get list of invited friends?

Comment: The invite dialog is not the same as the request dialog (now named FBSDKGameRequestDialog in v4.x). The game request dialog available to game apps only, and still has the same behavior in 4.x as it did in 3.x. The App Invite dialog is a completely new feature with a different API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no way** to get list of invited friends.

The issue was discussed with Facebook engineer Emil Hesslow at [Facebook Developer Community group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/889288034448045/). Here is relevant part of one of his comments:

> And if they expect their friends to show up in the app it is just
>   because it was working like that before. Not because everyone always
>   assumes that will happen if you invite someone.
>
> And no you can't get who they invited