# FBSDKAppInviteDialog: How to know when a friend have accepted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Using the `FBSDKAppInviteDialog` How do I know when a friend has accepted an invitation?

The result in the following delegate method do not give you the information:

```
- (void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results{
```

So do your App know when you are "App friends".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know for sure that you cannot get the ids or any information about the friends you invited using `FBSDKAppInviteDialog`. More information in this Question: [App invite dialog delegate methods result parameter contains no request id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937365/app-invite-dialog-delegate-methods-result-parameter-contains-no-request-id?rq=1)

And I'm pretty sure that there is no way to get the friends that accepted your invitation directly neither. You could use a Dynamic App Link end point with a referral code, though. You can have a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios#app_links

The above applies only if you are developing a non-game app. It is much easier if you are doing a game. Then you can use `FBSDKGameRequestDialog` or the `invitable_friends` method of the Graph API, if you want to draw a custom interface for that.

Unrelated directly to your question, this might be interesting for you if you are trying to implement a kind of referral system: https://developers.google.com/app-invites/